# jQuery DataTables yadcf greater-than-equal to (date)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yadcf

I am using the jQuery YADCF plugin to filter out a column of dates formatted mm-dd-yyyy. The plugin works beautifully out of the box, except it only shows an EXACT match on the dates. It will show me 03/06/2016 if that exact row is in the table, but I really want it to show 03/06/2016 and all dates after.

I have been trying to do this manually with DataTables and there's no real working or well-documented jQuery DataTables version out there that does a "greater than and equal to" date search.

Has anyone successfully done this with YADCF (or DataTables solo)?

Comment: http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html. The link shows you how to do integer min/max filtering. You can customize it to work for minimum date filtering.

Comment: Always a huge fan of using moment.js to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Have you used the range_date filter type? See third column filter on showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html and what about the custom function (select) filter? You can populate the select with any kind of values and do your own filter logic in it, see first column http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html

Comment: Hi @Daniel thank you for responding. When I use range_date I get "No Results" found no matter what I do. I also have two separate columns with dates, each that should have a single date filter that includes the selected date plus all future dates. Can I use a custom function with a datepicker? Is that my best bet?

Comment: each `range_date` filter works for single column - it can't filter multiple columns at once, if it does not work for you as it works on showcase post a jsbin/jsfillde link so I can see whats wrong

Comment: Hi @Daniel. Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lmqju9b/7/.

You can see the range date for column 4 does not work (try putting in 03/08 to 03/23, no results). The regular date filter column 5 matches perfectly, but I wish it would show all dates greater than or equal to.

The markup looks a little weird because I stripped this from a Drupal view.

Comment: simplify your sample to use date only (without time) in column and also use proper date format dd/mm/yyyy and try to see if its the time that messes the filtering or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My use case here was an edge case for YADCF, so I repurposed some code from http://codepen.io/markmichon/pen/tmeGD to get my filter working. I didn't use YADCF this time, but great to know it's out there. Big shout-out to Daniel, the plugin author, for responding to me!!

```
// converts date strings to a Date object, then normalized into a YYYYMMMDD format (ex: 20131220). Makes comparing dates easier. ex: 20131220 > 20121220
var normalizeDate = function(dateString) {
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    var normalized = date.getFullYear() + '' + (("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)) + '' + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return normalized;
}

var filterByDate = function(column, vesselDate) {
// Custom filter syntax requires pushing the new filter to the global filter array
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            var rowDate = (aData[column]).replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').match(/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/), // take my mm-dd-yyyy – timestamp format wrapped in hTML and strip it down to the mm-dd-yyy only
          start = normalizeDate(vesselDate); // use a normalized date (see code below)
          rowDate = normalizeDate(rowDate);
      // If our date from the row is between the start and end
      if (start <= rowDate) {
        return true;
      } else if (rowDate >= start && start !== ''){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    );
};

$('#dateStart').on('change keyup', function(){
    dateStart = $(this).val();
    filterByDate(3, dateStart); //passing the column value to the function
    $vesselSchedule.draw(); //updating the table
});

$('#dateEnd').on('change keyup', function(){
    dateEnd = $(this).val();
    filterByDate(4, dateEnd);
    $vesselSchedule.draw();
});
```

https://www.nwseaportalliance.com/operations/vessels#/ for a live example.